# Likelihood ratio test for $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $Y_1,...,Y_m \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

I am given a problem that asks me to perform a hypothesis testing where

$$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 \quad \text{vs} \quad H_1: \mu_1 \ne \mu_2$$

for  $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $Y_1,...,Y_m \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma^2)$.

I am also given a fixed value for $\sigma^2$, $n$, $m$, $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ to evaluate the test.

What bothers me here is that if I were asked to create a hypothesis test under this condition I would go to

$$\frac{\bar X - \bar Y - (\mu_1 - \mu_2)}{\sigma \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}}} = Z \sim N(0,1)$$

and work around it.

However, the problem is not 100% clear about how to go about with the "likelihood ratio test".

One of my understandings is that the likelihood ratio is

$$\Lambda = \frac{L(\theta_0)}{L(\hat{\theta}_{MLE})}$$

and

$$-2 \ln \Lambda \rightarrow \chi^2_1  $$

Another thing that bothers me here is that if the problem is asking about ratio of likelyhoods

$$\frac{L(\mu_1)}{L(\mu_2)}$$

I am not confident that this behaves the same way that $\Lambda$ does.

Since the given $n$ and $m$ are large I am assuming that the asymptotic distribution is well approximated as a Chi-squared.

May I have some advice on how to proceed?

I tried to see what happens with the ratio of likelihoods but it gave me an expression

$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{i=1}^m Y_i^2$$

which I cannot deduce an exact value from the given information. . .

Comment: Something missing here: Hypotheses mention population means $\mu_1, \mu_2,$ but both normal populations are specified to have $0$ means. Suspect title and 3rd line of question may be wrong. // Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you for noticing. I will fix that right away.

Comment: OK. The LR test rejects at the 5% level when $|Z| \ge 1.96.$

Comment: Maybe you used the original wrong info to get the puzzling result for the LR test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help, everyone.

For future references, this is the conclusion that I will draw for now.

Let $W = \bar{X} - \bar{Y}$.

Then we know

$$W \sim N(\mu_1-\mu_2,\sigma^2 \left(\frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{m} \right))$$

This way we can perform a likelihood ratio test based on a single observation of $W$ whose distribution we know that it is normal.

Thus, using the fact that the MLE is $\frac{1}{n+m} \sum_{i=1}^{n+m}W_i = W_1$

we perform the LR test with the hypothesis

$$H_0: \mu_1-\mu_2 \quad \text{vs} \quad H_1:\mu_1-\mu_2 \ne0$$

where the likelihood ratio is

$$\Lambda = \exp\left[\frac{W_1^2}{-2\sigma^2(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m})}\right]$$

so

$$\chi^2 = -2 \ln \Lambda = \frac{W_1^2}{\sigma^2(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m})}$$.

I believe that this conforms with the fact that a square of a standard normal distribution is chi-squared, so it is more of a matter of which distribution to use when doing the hypothesis test.

In conclusion, we can reject the null when

$$\chi^2 \ge \chi^2_{\alpha}(1)$$

Answer (score 0):

I will let you finish your derivation of the LR test. Here
is a numerical example of its application.

Suppose you have 20 observations, simulated using R statistical software, from $N(50,25)$ and from
$N(53,25),$ then you have the following summary statistics:

```
set.seed(717)  # for reproducibility
x1 = rnorm(20, 50, 5);  x2 = rnorm(20, 53, 5)
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  43.97   49.14   50.33   50.78   53.27   57.94 
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  44.88   50.48   52.83   53.29   55.23   62.71
```

[image]

Suppose you want to test $H_0: \mu_1=\mu_1$ vs.$H_1: \mu_1\ne\mu_1.$
Then the $Z$ statistic can be found as follows:

```
se = 5*sqrt(1/20 + 1/20)
z = (50.33-52.83)/se; z
[1] -1.581139
```

Because $|Z| = 1.581 < 1.96$ you cannot reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.

Because data were simulated for this example, we know $\mu_1=50 \ne \mu_2=53.$ And, indeed $\bar X_1 < \bar X_2.$ However, 20 observations
with $\sigma^2 = 25$ are not sufficient to detect this difference
from the data.